# Avoid laptop display with monitor when switching user

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I have a small laptop with Ubuntu connected to a tv monitor via HDMI. I have set **Single Display** in Ubuntu because I'm working all the time with just the big screen. However, every time I switch between users (Desktop -  Switch User...) I lost my monitor screen and I have to login from the laptop screen. The same when I first login.

How can I solve this?